# Installing docker container within Plesk

Tags: docker, redirect, plesk, kiwi-tcms

I followed https://docs.plesk.com/de-DE/obsidian/administrator-guide/plesk-administration/verwenden-von-docker.75823/ to install the latest version under Plesk.

All I got is "To many redirects".
Has anybody a how-to for using Kiwi TCMS under Plesk?

I did already a full update/upgrade for Plesk and Ubuntu **20.04** LTS. Didn't solve the issue. I tried, in addition, to use **6.38** from docker-hub.